# Upload video using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to upload a video from android device to server using Retrofit2 and end up getting error '400 Bad Request'. Below is the implementation. Could somebody help to fix the error?

```
public interface RetrofitService {
/**
 * Upload Videos to Server
 */
@Multipart
@POST("store/S3")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadToServer(@Query("key") String ServerAPI,
                                      @Query("mimetype") String videoMimeType,
                                      @Query("path") String path,
                                      @Query("container") String container,
                                      @Query("policy") String policy,
                                      @Query("signature") String signature,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part video,
                                      @Part("type") String videoType,
                                      @Part("name") String videoName );
```

}

Client implemetation in helper.java

```
  private void uploadVideos(String videUri, String policy, String signature){
    String BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/api/";
    String EXAMPLE_API_KEY = "xebfc";
    String mimeType = "video/mp4";
    String path = "mezzanine_videos/";
    String container = S3_BUCKET;

    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File videoFile = new File(videoUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send the actual file
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);

    String videoType = "video/mp4";
    String videoName = "video.mp4";

    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadToServer( EXAMPLE_API_KEY, mimeType, path, container, policy, signature, vFile, videoType, videoName);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Successful Response");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Response", "Failure Response");
        }
    }); }
```

Server implementation works fine because I get a valid response by doing a curl post like below.

```
curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@animation.mov "https://www.example.com/api/store/S3?key= xebfc&mimetype=video%2Fmp4&path=mezzanine_videos/&container= S3_BUCKET&policy=ppppp&signature=ssss
```

Comment: Add logging interceptor to your retrofit instance and update the question please. Are you sure using MediaType.parse("video/*") instead of exact type and ''video" as name of part?

Comment: Thanks for your response @KonstantinBerkow , MediaType.parse("video/*") or MediaType.parse("video") is resulting the same error. I will add the formatted logging Interceptor in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging on MultipartBody.Part.createFormData, figured out that the name was not matching with my backend implementation. Below code fixed the issue.

```
    MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileUpload", videoFile.getName(), fileBody);
```

Rest of the code is same as mentioned above.